# When installing Windows update msu manually, get "The update is not applicable to your compute"?

Tags: windows, windows-update

I want to get some system files in Windows for testing, so, I created a VM with windows server 2019, I have downloaded several updates, one of them is KB5016623.
When I start to install it by clicking *.msu file, but I get "The update is not applicable to your compute"
The file should be correct, what's wrong?

Comment: Which update? Which version? What is your system and which specific update version did you download and try to install?

Comment: @music2myear It's not a specific update problem, I want to provide a common question and a common way to solve problem.

Comment: Wanting to provide a good answer to a problem you've faced is good, but the question will need more detail or it is very likely to be closed. Error codes, using phrases like "I am getting the same error installing multiple updates I've downloaded directly from Microsoft..." etc.

Answer (score 0):

Check your update KB, maybe you need to install stackupdate firstly!

for example, I want to install KB5016623 for windows server 2019 from page "https://msrc.microsoft.com/update-guide/vulnerability/CVE-2022-34696", check KB5016623's description, it says:
[image]

So, we need to install KB5005112 firstly. Click that link, and find this part:
[image]

Click Microsoft Update Catalog to get KB5005112's update, after installing it, the error will disapear.